# Tslint --exclude is not working

Tags: angular, tslint

Seemed like ts lint -e/--exclude is not working, or I do something wrong.
I have tslint 4.5.1 installed. When Im trying to use CLI as `tslint -e path_to_file`, it said that files missing, even when I'm using this command with full path to the file. Could you advise please how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. I think that files missing errprs may be caused by using 'ng' directly; try using `npm run lint` instead.

If you use cli,you can revise `.angular-cli.json` like this:

```
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**","**/path/**"]
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**","**/path/**"]
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**","**/path/**"]
}
],
```